# Use alertDialog builder for preferenceDialog

Tags: android, android-listview, android-alertdialog, dialog-preference

I am trying to make a custom preference using aa multi select list that I want to programmatically fill in. I tried to create a custom DialogPreference as seen below and used a AlertDialog builder to create my dialog. The problem is that piecing together different tutorials, I am implementing/overriding onCreateDialogView() which needs to return a View. I am not sure if it is possible to get an AlertDialog.Builder to return a View.

```
public class notifyPreferances extends DialogPreference {

//Tag used for logcat
String TAG = "notifyPreferances";

//Store values to diplay in mutliselect list
CharSequence[] selections;

//Constructor
notifyPreferances(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, CharSequence[] options) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setPersistent(false);
    selections = options;

}


@Override
protected View onCreateDialogView() {

    //Initialize Builer
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());

    //Set Dialog Title
    builder.setTitle("Lights/Groups")

    //Set the items for the list and the onclick actions
    builder.setItems(selections, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Selected Option: " + selections[item]);
        }
    });

    return builder.create(); 

    return super.onCreateDialogView();


}

@Override
protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
    super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult);
}
}
```

Any thoughts or recommendation on how I can solve this problem be either returning the builder as a view, or a different way to programatically create the Dialog would be greatly appreciated.

Here are the two tutorials I am trying to combine:
[Concise way of writing new DialogPreference classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505845/concise-way-of-writing-new-dialogpreference-classes) and
[Android: Select items in a multi-select ListView inside AlertDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20017329/android-select-items-in-a-multi-select-listview-inside-alertdialog)